# Java - How to iterate json objects keys and values pair?

Tags: java, json, loops, jsonparser

Here below the json format:

`Document{
{Social=4, Productivity=5, Personalization=1, Entertainment=5, Music & Audio=4, Finance=7, Tools=9, Travel & Local=1, Food & Drink=3, Card=1, Photography=5, OTHERS=4, Shopping=4, Maps & Navigation=2, Communication=5, Business=3, Video Players & Editors=3
}}`

Here I need only keys no need of values.
I am expecting this kind of output:

```
{
            "name": "Social",
            "value": "Social"
},
{
            "name": "Productivity",
            "value": "Productivity"
}
{
            "name": "Personalization",
            "value": "Personalization"
}
{
            "name": "Entertainment",
            "value": "Entertainment"
}
{
            "name": "Music & Audio",
            "value": "Music & Audio"
}
{
            "name": "Finance",
            "value": "Finance"
}
{
            "name": "Tools",
            "value": "Tools"
}
{
            "name": "Travel & Local",
            "value": "Travel & Local"
}
{
            "name": "Food & Drink",
            "value": "Food & Drink"
}
{
            "name": "Card",
            "value": "Card"
}
{
            "name": "Photography",
            "value": "Photography"
}
{
            "name": "OTHERS",
            "value": "OTHERS"
}
{
            "name": "Shopping",
            "value": "Shopping"
}
{
            "name": " Maps & Navigation",
            "value": " Maps & Navigation"
}
{
            "name": "Communication",
            "value": "Communication"
}
{
            "name": "Business",
            "value": "Business"
}
{
            "name": "Productivity",
            "value": "Productivity"
}
```

I am not getting a proper solution.

Comment: which language you are using? javascript? and also redit the question its not clear what you want to achieve and output what you have written is correct?

Comment: Actually sorry didn't mentioned the language actually using java language I need an output like see above the names and values json format but I don't know if u know plz support

Comment: What have you tried? You have not posted any Java code or what the actual concrete problem is. If you haven't even started, read a tutorial for example https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp.htm.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments and I am getting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (Document doc : documents) {
            doc.entrySet().forEach(v -> {
                SegmentValueOptions inputValues = new SegmentValueOptions();
                inputValues.setName(v.getKey());
                inputValues.setValue(inputValues.getName());
                inputValList.add(inputValues);
            });
    }
    }
```